# Getting URL Parameters in groovy

Tags: groovy

Suppose i have this as a URL

`https://localhost/?username=john_small` and i want to get the username and display for instance :

in PHP i can do something like this

```
$username = $_GET['username']
```

then showing back what i did i go like this

```
<?php echo $username;?>
```

now in Java i also can do something like this

```
String username = request.getParameters("username");
```

and should i want to display it i do something like

```
<% "Hello" + <%=username%>; %>
```

For instance now i want to do the same in groovy, can i use the same thing like as it is in Java i am lost of ideas here

Comment: Do you want to parse such URL or are you operating inside a web-server? Both PHP and Java example would indicate the later, but your question does not state any environment you run your Groovy code in.  Can we assume plain Groovy and adding additional libraries is no problem?

Comment: @cfrick, in PHP i am using apache as webserver and in java JSP and i am using Tomcat as webserver

Comment: Ok, but now you are using groovy, so this does not answer my question.

Comment: i am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Does the java code you provided not work? There are simple changes to make it groovier (e.g., `String` -> `def`, dropping semicolons, removing parens) are mostly syntactic sugar and won't add any real functionality. (Without more context, you'd probably end up with `def username = request.parameters['username']`)

Answer (score 1):

I think I am late to answer this question as I just got chance to work with SOAP UI:

Following works:

```
  def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("Request Name")
  testStep.requestProperties.each { it ->
    log.info(it.getKey()+ " " + it.getValue().getValue())
 }
```